# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 , Syntax error on LEFT JOIN Condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mariadb

We have got an error while we join two table using left join condition with a third table.

Here is an error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON(cnt.PKDID
>   = pd.PKDID)) as led on `led`.`PKID` = `pkg`.`PKID` where `pkg`.`Sta' at line 3 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from`packages`as`pkg
>   `left join`events`as`ev`on`ev`.`EvnId`=`pkg`.`EvnId` left join
>   (SELECT pd.PKDID, pd.BsNaId, cnt.ContentList, bn.nature FROM
>   package_dets as pd, busi_natures as bn WHERE pd.BsNaId = bn.BsNaId
>
> LEFT JOIN(SELECT PKID, PKDID, ContentList FROM package_detcontents
>   GROUP BY PKDID)cnt\n
>               ON(cnt.PKDID = pd.PKDID)) as led on `led`.`PKID` = `pkg`.`PKID` where `pkg`.`Status` = Active and `ev`.`enventNm` =
>   birthday)

Here is my code i have got error into it.

```
->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT pd.PKDID, pd.BsNaId, cnt.ContentList, bn.nature FROM package_dets as pd, busi_natures as bn WHERE pd.BsNaId = bn.BsNaId 
    LEFT JOIN(SELECT PKID, PKDID, ContentList FROM package_detcontents GROUP BY PKDID)cnt
    ON(cnt.PKDID = pd.PKDID)) as led"), 
    function($join){
    $join->on("led.PKID","=","pkg.PKID");
    })
```

And here is complete code

```
$package = DB::table("packages as pkg")
->select(DB::raw("pkg.PKID, pkg.EvnId, pkg.PkgNm, pkg.link, pkg.cross_price, pkg.off_percent, pkg.images, pkg.price, pkg.forpeople, pkg.Minsrating, pkg.Plsrating, pkg.remark, pkg.Status, led.nature, ev.enventNm"))
      ->leftJoin("events as ev","ev.EvnId","=","pkg.EvnId")
->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT pd.PKDID, pd.BsNaId, cnt.ContentList, bn.nature FROM package_dets as pd, busi_natures as bn WHERE pd.BsNaId = bn.BsNaId 
    LEFT JOIN(SELECT PKID, PKDID, ContentList FROM package_detcontents GROUP BY PKDID)cnt
    ON(cnt.PKDID = pd.PKDID)) as led"), 
    function($join){
    $join->on("led.PKID","=","pkg.PKID");
    })
->where("pkg.Status", "=", "Active")
->where("ev.enventNm", "=", $envent)
->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with your query syntax. This should be your query-

```
SELECT pd.PKDID, 
   pd.BsNaId, 
   cnt.ContentList, 
   bn.nature
FROM package_dets AS pd
 INNER JOIN busi_natures AS bn ON pd.BsNaId = bn.BsNaId
 /*Above INNER JOIN can be any other JOIN as per your requirement*/
 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT PKID, 
           PKDID, 
           ContentList
    FROM package_detcontents
    GROUP BY PKID,PKDID,ContentList
) cnt 
ON cnt.PKDID = pd.PKDID;
```

Comment: now this error is showing  `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'eventm.package_detcontents.PKID' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `packages` as `pkg` left join `events` as `ev` on `ev`.`EvnId` = `pkg`.`EvnId` left join (SELECT pd.PKDID, pd.BsNaId, cnt.ContentList, bn.nature FROM package_dets AS pd`

Comment: @SagarCoder I have updated the script. Can you please check now?